# Why the SQL shows MySQL Error?

Tags: mysql

Why this sql shows mysql error?

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments
JOIN wp_commentmeta ON wp_comments.comment_id =wp_commentmeta.comment_id 
AND wp_commentmeta.meta_key = 'somekey'                        
AND wp_comments.comment_post_ID = '1'
```

error string

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN wp_commentmeta ON  
wp_comments.comment_id =wp_commentmeta.comment_id A' at line 2
```

Please Advice me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `join` in a `delete` statement you have to specify from which tables you want to delete

```
DELETE c 
FROM wp_comments c
JOIN wp_commentmeta m ON c.comment_id = m.comment_id 
                      AND m.meta_key = 'somekey'                        
                      AND c.comment_post_ID = '1'
```